# Is there a Sass-style map-keys function in Less?

Tags: sass, less

I found Scss have the map-keys function to get keys of properties:

```css
$properties: (transform: translateX(100%) translate(0%), opacity: 0 1);

transition-property: map-keys($properties);
```

which will output:

```css
transition-property: transform, opacity;
```

I tried but not found less have this useful function.

I'm using v3.10.3

How can I use less to get keys from Map?

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer in less:

```
@properties: {
  transform: translateX(100%) translate(0%);
  opacity: 0 1;
};

.extract-prop(@properties) {
  each(@properties, {
    transition-property+: @key;
  })
}

.extract-prop(@properties);
```

Will get the output:

```
transition-property: transform, opacity;
```